# serverside highchart with play framework

Tags: playframework, highcharts

I was trying to generate a chart using highchart's serverside API in my play framework app.

However the most basic error happens:

```
The file /app/controllers/Application.java could not be compiled. Error raised is : org.one2team.highcharts.shared.ChartOptions cannot be resolved
```

due to the line:

```
import org.one2team.highcharts.shared.ChartOptions;
```

I have copied all the required jars into the lib directory of the app.

Not sure what I am missing.

**Edit 1**: I created a jar file of the downloaded code from github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export.
The compilation goes thro fine when I use the complete classname eg "org.one2team.highcharts.shared.ChartOptions" instead of just ChartOptions.

During runtime, I see the error
NoClassDefFoundError occured : org/one2team/highcharts/server/JSMHighchartsFactory

*play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException:
 org/one2team/highcharts/server/JSMHighchartsFactory

```
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:229)

    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
org/one2team/highcharts/server/JSMHighchartsFactory

```
    at examples.SamplesFactory.<init>(SamplesFactory.java:354)

    at examples.SamplesFactory.<clinit>(SamplesFactory.java:357)*
```

This implies it was able to resolve SamplesFactory class, but not JSMHighchartsFactory.
I do find this in the jar file.
 Does it mean that during runtime, it is not being picked?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you download the one2team.highcharts source from https://github.com/one2team/highcharts-serverside-export?  I only see source java files, no jars.  Where did you find them?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded the source from github.com. I was able to run the example provided in the downloaded source. The jar files that I mentioned were the ones in its lib directory - ../highcharts-serverside-export/tree/master/lib. I assume that I need to create the jars for them myself. So I have started down the path of creating a play-framework module. I am having some issues there. I thought it could be due to 'ant' not being installed on my system. Tried installing it and there are some installation errors in it -Error getting POM for 'javax.media:jai-core' from the repository

Answer (score 0):

How did you added the HighCharts Library? In your IDE directly? If so I would try this:

```
play clean yourProject
```

then:

```
play eclipsify yourProject
```

After that you could try running your application again or even IMPORTING the entire project again in Eclipse.

Comment: I copied the dependent jars into the app's lib directory. I also did the eclipsify and added them in eclipse. However as Mark points out, those jar's are not the jars generated by the "highcharts-serverside-export". Next step would be to create the jar's using conventional method and then check if the Class is resolved!!